# Is it possible to prevent Eclipse from closing up the project space when you close the app?

Tags: eclipse

I have a Java project in Eclipse that mirrors a directory structure on my hard drive and every time I open Eclipse I have to manually open all of the folders to see the source files inside them. Is there a way to avoid this so that everything stays open between app sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the CNF alone (the Common Navigation Framework), I don't think so.

But with **[Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)** (which is part of certain [Eclipse packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php)), you can because the Mylyn task will keep the relevant files/classes/methods visible from one session ot the next.

[image]

Comment: I just installed Mylyn but after restarting, it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @pnut: did you activated the mylyn mode (button just right of the inverted triangle, on the top right of the Package Explorer)?

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't locate the button where you recommended to look. This is a screenshot I took on my machine of the section of the screen I think you're referring to: http://imgur.com/v9RSK.jpg

Comment: @pnut: it is just *below* your screenshot. You see it for instance in http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/new/images/3.3/cdt-bridge.png or in http://eclipse.org/mylyn/new/images/2.1/focus-linking-disable.png. But if Mylyn is installed but not visible, that may be simply because it is not activated in your current perspective.